# What's the point of middlewares replacing built in Express.js functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There's [quite a list of Express.js middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware.html) replacing built-in functions. For example:

> *body-parser* - Parse HTTP request body. Replaces built-in function *express.bodyParser*

What do they mean when they say "replaces built-in function"? Do those replacements provide any improvement on top of built-in versions? I mean I do not see any point in using additional modules, if they don't. I'm asking 'cause I do not see it mentioned anywhere, at least in the middleware documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it overrides default behavior or object natively given in the app.

Excerpt from the doc, for example the `res.json`:

> This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser.

...

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the
>   request object after the middleware (i.e. `req.body`), or an empty
>   object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type was not
>   matched, or an error occurred.

The body-parser in question is useful for me, I used it to recover the data transmitted in an post form for example.

Since the update to express v4 original builtin functions [were separated into standalone modules](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/History.md#400--2014-04-09). Now each module is independent but still included as a dependency in the [package.json of express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json).

It is somewhat confusing.

Comment: So do you say that they've extracted middlewares into standalone npm modules? I'm using express 4.17.1 and the built-in function is still available.

Comment: Yes it's what I say, I suggest to look at the package.json of express.js, you'll see that there are in... https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json.

Comment: Ok, so they've extracted them, and still provide built-in functions that rely on them internally? So from what I understand there's absolutely no point in listing those middleware as dependencies in my own project or using them directly, since express itself already has them as such?

Comment: In fact I think you're right to don't include them in your dependencies... I use the alpha version of express 5, and they are still in the package.json. Even I read somewhere that it benefic to include the module you use in your package.json, a little story: One day You use the underscore module provide from another module.  Another futur day, this module doesn't include it anymore... You see what I want to say ? But it's not the case as I say you for your case...

Comment: The whole backstory behind my question was that I continue to stumble upon tutorials around the web that interchangeably use either built-in versions or external modules, and from what I understand now they do not get the difference either and just use them, because others do (in fact I see now that my question got two votes to close as *"too broad"*... huh, what's broad about it?!).

Comment: I think it's a crucial point, maybe you should somehow incorporate it into your answer and I will accept it as a correct one.

Comment: That's done. If you've some point to add, do not hesitate, it can just be better for future users in your case.